# unix timestamps in createdAt, updatedAt & deletedAt fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm using SequlizeJS ORM in my ExpressJS application to communicate with MariaDB. I'm working with existing database scheme so I can't change data types of the fields. Existing database uses unix timestamps in createdAt, updatedAt & deletedAt fields. Now I need to follow that for the new ExpressJS app too.

In each modal I use the following Sequelize hooks to convert createdAt & updatedAt fields to unix timestamps.

```
hooks: {
    beforeCreate: (instance, options) => {
        instance.dataValues.createdAt = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
        instance.dataValues.updatedAt = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    },
    beforeUpdate: (instance, options) => {
        instance.dataValues.updatedAt = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    }
}
```

but the thing is that I can't set deletedAt as a timestamp on beforeBulkDestroy hook. Can anyone please help me to resolve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: What's the problem with beforeBulkDestroy()?  Is there an error message, or does it just not work as expected?

Comment: beforeBulkDestroy() only accept options, can't modify the instance .. or do I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to try - the individualHooks option calls the beforeDestroy() hook for each instance.  This can be applied at the query level:

```
 db.myFunkyModel.destroy({
    where: { 
       'field' : { [Op.like]: '%someValue%' }
    },
    individualHooks : true
  });
```

Or at a broader level:

```
 const sequelizeDb = new Sequelize(
    ...      
    {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      ....
      define: {
        ....
        individualHooks : true
      }
      ....
    });
```

Take a look at the Model Hooks section of [the manual](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/hooks.html) for potential performance hits from individualHooks.

Comment: I tried using individualHooks but it didn't resolve the issue. still can't handle unix timestamp on deletedAt field.

Comment: Strange - my tests worked correctly.  Is your individual hook being executed?  You could test with  a log message as below.

`hooks: {
    beforeDestroy: (instance, options) => {
        console.log('*** beforeDestroy *** ',instance.dataValues);
  instance.dataValues.deletededAt = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    },
 ....`

Comment: Please can you check the following screen shots ? It's giving me the same error as in the past.

https://imgur.com/a/EI4bBlE

Comment: It looks like the deletedAt date is being set by Sequelize and NOT from your hook. This seems odd, given you were able to hook this for create and update.  Maybe the soft delete with `timestamps: true, paranoid: true,` cannot be hooked?  Unfortunately, the only solution I can think of right now is to manually code the soft delete.... and that's kind of ugly.

Comment: yep. I'm thinking about the same thing. maybe do a raw query but It' ugly.  :(